# How can you cascade a configuration file to submodules in powershell?

Tags: powershell, config

I have a root module with several helper submodules that I want to keep as loosely coupled as possible.  The folder layout is something like this.

```
RootModule/
    Entrypoint.psm1
    config.psm1
    Submodule1/
        submodule1-entrypoint.psm1
    Submodule2/
        submodule2-entrypoint.psm1
```

Now the configuration file is a hashtable with comments and it exports a function that just returns that hashtable.

```
$config = @{
    # config item one
    "LogLevel" = "Info";
}

function Ininitialize-ConfigData {
    return $config
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Ininitialize-ConfigData
```

Now I would like to change the LogLevel and have that config item cascade down to all the submodules so that I could hardcode the

```
$InformationPreference = $config.LogLevel
```

How would I pass that configuration on to the next module without having the module search up from its position and import the configuration itself?

Comment: While writing this I found this post which answers my question.  But I'm hoping that this might help others.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897511/powershell-module-pass-a-parameter-while-importing-module

Comment: So since I can't add an answer I found that by exporting my config hashtable variable from the main module in my project and specifying the NestedModules  inthe psd1 that will rely on that variable and it just worked.  This avoids the problem of remembering to pass that config to each module because as the number of related modules grew it got annoying to add the mapping between each module. I would like to submit this as an answer to this question but it's already marked as a duplicate.